# Oracle 12c DB View Error - ORA-01810: format code appears twice

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

This is my view below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW STUDENT_DETAILS AS
SELECT 
          COALESCE(Dept.deptname, stu.deptname,' ') AS deptname,
          CASE WHEN college.JOIN_DATE IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE TO_DATE(college.JOIN_DATE, 'dd-MM-yyyy') || ' '  END AS JOINDATE
FROM 
          College_register college
             LEFT JOIN Department dept ON college.stuid=dept.stuid 
             LEFT JOIN student stu ON college.stuid=student.stuid;
```

When I execute the below query I get the Error " ORA-01810: format code appears twice"

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT_DETAILS;
```

But when I execute as below (Just the select query without the view) I **do not** see the above error.

```
SELECT 
          COALESCE(Dept.deptname, stu.deptname,' ') AS deptname,
          CASE WHEN college.JOIN_DATE IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE TO_DATE(college.JOIN_DATE, 'dd-MM-yyyy') || ' '  END AS JOINDATE
FROM 
          College_register college
             LEFT JOIN Department dept ON college.stuid=dept.stuid 
             LEFT JOIN student stu ON college.stuid=student.stuid;
```

Comment: Neither query is syntactically correct.  Neither will run, because of a trailing comma.

Comment: Sorry, Edited my question and removed the comma. It was a typo.

Comment: is this the full query?

Comment: Yes it is the full query

Comment: what is the datatype of `JOIN_DATE`?

Comment: data type of JOIN_DATE ==> DATE

Comment: If JOIN_DATE is indeed of DATE data type (are you 100% sure?) then it doesn't make sense to wrap it within TO_DATE. TO_DATE converts **strings** to dates. Oracle, stupidly in my opinion, instead of throwing an error when you supply a date to TO_DATE, will convert the date to a string, implicitly, and then try to convert back to a date. Your issue MAY be caused by a mismatch between your NLS_DATE_FORMAT (what is it?) and the explicit format model you supplied in TO_DATE.

Comment: Actually, it seems obvious that you wanted to convert to a string. In that case, you need to use TO_CHAR, not TO_DATE.

Comment: The queries still aren't valid. Why not show your actual code, and include the table structures and sample data? We shouldn't have to try to guess what you are really doing.